# Adding/simulating a Delete Button in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with some sections and rows.

I want to simulate the Delete button that appears when you are editing the Contacts, a red button (the size of the cell).

Should I use a button for this? I've tried to add a background image for the button but I can't 'repeat' it, maybe I have to create one with the final size.

I can change the background color of the cell but would be a 'solid' color.

What's the best option?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was a case sensitive.

The Simulator it's NOT case sensitive, but the iPhone it is ...

thanks,

r.

Comment: editing a question two years after it was made, well, I think it was one of my very first questions here, apologizes. Also I don't understand the down vote...